# linking fields between a form and a subform fails

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm stuck with an x-file trying to do something simple that I did thousands of times but now fails in a weird way.

I have a parent form called **TASKS** and a subform called **TASKS_LIST**. They are populated with recordsets that share some fields. The two important fields here are **BUNDLE_ID** (long) and **TASK_ID** (long).

Depending on certaing condition I want to link the subform with the parent form by the field **BUNDLE_ID** or by the field **TASK_ID**.

This is how I do it ->

First, in another form, I open the **TASKS** form like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "TASKS", , , mVntCrit, , , intType
```

Where **mVntCrit** filters the records in the form and **intType** is an int with two possible values (1,2) passed by as an openArgs.

Then, on the Form_Open event of the parent form I do this:

```
    Dim intTypeAs Integer
    
    intType= Nz(OpenArgs)
    
    Select Case intType
        
        Case 1
            Me.TASKS_LIST.LinkChildFields = "BUNDLE_ID"
            Me.TASKS_LIST.LinkMasterFields = "BUNDLE_ID"

        Case 2
            Me.TASKS_LIST.LinkChildFields = "TASK_ID"
            Me.TASKS_LIST.LinkMasterFields = "TASK_ID"
            
    End Select
```

When I execute the code it appears an error message on the instructions that changes the linked fields:

> Runtime Error '2101'
> The specified value is not valid for this property.

I've tried/checked:

1. Initialize first the property values with an empty string to reset
   the linking fields.
2. Change the order of the instructions, changing the value of the LinkMasterFields property first (althoug in principle the child goes first).
3. Compile, compact and repair.
4. Checked that the fields to link are the same type and have no nulls.
5. Checked that the fields name are correct.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This I've seen when a fieldname is either misspelled, missing, or of an unexpected data type.

Comment: @Gustav That wasn't the case, I triple checked. Fortunately I found the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I realized that the code worked for some records and failed for other records. So I needed to know what's different between the records that work and those than do not work.

Ok, in the original form that opens de **TASKS** parent form, there is a list of elements from a table **T1**. In the TASKS and **TASKS_LIST** forms the table **T1** joins with a table **T2** by a field **F**.

When I open the **TASKS** form, I filter its records with a certain criterion being F=Some Id from **T1**. The thing is: there are some records where this Id exists in **T1** but not in **T2**. Therefore, when I open and filter the **TASKS** form with an Id that does not exists in **T2** the form return no records. If **TASKS** do not return any records, **TASKS_LIST** do not return any records either.

In that case, when **TASKS_LIST** return no records, if I try to meddle with properties of the form (in this case .**LinkChildFields** and .**LinkMasterFields**) an error happens. On the other hand, when **TASKS_LIST** return some records, I can alter the form properties without problem.

Therefore I deduce that accessing and altering some properties of forms that return no records is forbidden for some reason. It reminds me of the classic error when trying to access the value of a texbox in a form without records.